# PreparedStatement with sql comment

Tags: java, sql

Can I have parameters in the comment of a PreparedStatement in java. 
Something like -

```
PreparedStatement stmnt = con.prepareStatement("/*blah = ? */ UPDATE TBL SET col1 = ? ")
```

I tried it but it doesn't work, is there any other way. Thanks.

Comment: I'm left with the question of why?  The database won't care

Comment: actually there is a publisher-subscriber system which reads mysql transaction logs and pushes updates to the subscribers. This systems just understands the comments added to sql.
I am working on adding these comments so that publisher could work.

Comment: It means all your sql will have Java comment or sql comment syntax ?

Comment: sql will have sql comment syntax. Here sql comment and java comment syntax is same as both of them are /* COMMENT */

Comment: @RishiKeshDwivedi did you try it without the question mark? the PreparedStatement will interpret that as a parameter.

Comment: @simo.3792095 : I don't get what do you mean by without question mark. Can you give me an example.

Comment: @RishiKeshDwivedi I was just pointing out that your comment was "/*blah = ? */", and the parser for the string used by PreparedStatement interprets question marks (?) as place holders for parameters.  So without being able to see what your error was, it is possible that this was the issue (although I doubt it).

Comment: @simo.3792095 : Unfortunately it doesn't work this way. Strings are not materialized before they are sent to mysql. Both query template and parameters are sent to mysql and then mysql uses the passed parameters to generate actual query. Here it just ignores comments and leaves it as it is.

Answer (score -6):

You can use String.format() to add a parameter.

```
String myBlah = "BlahBlah!";    
PreparedStatement stmnt = con.prepareStatement(String.format("/*blah = %s */ UPDATE TBL SET col1 = ? ",myBlah))
```

This will print the variable myBlah in place of %s

Comment: An issue here is that by changing the comment one will be reparsing each time thus loosing the benefit of prepared statements that they don't need to be reparsed and recompiled , though still get the protection agains SQL injection